# Your connection to this site is not secure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I´ve created a EC2 instance, installed a service and I was able to routed it to my address with Route 53. So I can go to example.com/myservice and see it on the browser.

However, in the browser, I get a small info card in the address bar that says

```
"Not secure" and information about not entering sensitive information.
```

What does this message mean? How can I avoid this message? What do I need to change in my existing setup?

All info is welcome, as this is fairly new for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you are connecting to your website using `HTTP` protocol, not `HTTPS`. `HTTP` is not secure as all data is in **plain text**, while in `HTTPS` your data is **encrypted**.

To rectify the issue you can install an SSL certificate **directly on your instance** or leverage **Load Balancer** or **CloudFront** in front of the instance.

Some useful links from **AWS documentation**:

- [Tutorial: Configure SSL/TLS on Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html) for direct installation of the certificate
- [Add an HTTPS Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#add-https-listener) for Application Load Balancer
- [Using Alternate Domain Names and HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html) for CloudFront